# Is it possible to send email from observer using SMTP

Tags: magento2, email

Is it possible to send email to customer when he place an order

this is my event.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework/Event/etc/events.xsd'>
   <event name='checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'>
        <observer
                name='Pulsestorm_HelloWorldMVVM_HelloWorld'
                instance='Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Observer\HelloWorld'
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

and this is my observer

```
<?php

namespace Pulsestorm\HelloWorldMVVM\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class HelloWorld implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_orderRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_orderRepositoryInterface = $orderRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * customer register event handler
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    $order = $this->_orderRepositoryInterface->get($orderIds[0]);
    $items =$order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $productIds = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $productIds[]= $item->getProductId();
    }

    //custoemr id
    $customerEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail();

   }


}
```

In $customerEmail i got customer mail id after that i have no idea how to send email using SMTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you already configure smtp. if not please refer this [link](http://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-mail-using-your-smtp-detail/) for send mail using your smtp.

**key code of sending mail**

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
class ClassName implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $storeManager;
protected $_transportBuilder;
protected $inlineTranslation;
public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $smi,TransportBuilder $tb,StateInterface $si)
{        
    $this->storeManager=$smi;
    $this->_transportBuilder=$tb;
    $this->inlineTranslation=$si;
}
public function yourFunctionName()
{
       $templateOptions = array('area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' => $cname,
            'message'   => 'We processed your order ID '.$orederid.'. We will contact you soon in mail for the acknowledgement if you not receive mail within 4 hours please get help from support@xxx.com'
        );
        $from = array('email' => "xxxxx@xxx.xxx", 'name' => 'AnyName');
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $to = array('xxxxx@xxx.xxx');
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
            ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
            ->setFrom($from)
            ->addTo($to)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
   } 
}
```

please note it `setTemplateIdentifier('order_template')` so you need to create `order_template`. for create email template refer this [link](https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/)

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\MailException): 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. s63sm41970461pfb.52 - gsmtp

Comment: plz help this error is coming after using your code

Comment: I thought it is a mail configuration issue not code so  refer https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/54111996 . here only the problem or the entire system does not send mail? let test with subcribe mail in footer form and check did you receive any mail from your store? if not, definitely you are not configure smtp properly

Comment: thank you @Bilal for your help now my code is running very well except template is not showing on mail (blank email) . I will check my code again

Comment: plz tell why blank email is sent. i have created a template with template id "order_template" in email_templates.xml in etc folder

Comment: If I'm using plain mail() function inside method - everything works. With your code I can't get result - I'm not receiving emails. What is the problem could be?

Comment: @BilalUsean I want send email from observer too, means I want to send email same as customer receives when order place .